# Como adicionar/remover sombras de um elemento com "position: sticky" conforme a rolagem?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabela-html

Fiz uma tabela com o *header* e a última coluna fixos utilizando `position: sticky`. Para passar uma impressão de que ela está acima de outras colunas/linhas, utilizei `box-shadow`, mas fica estranho deixar o `box-shadow` quando a linha ou coluna está com a posição `relative` (visualmente falando, [o comportamento de um `position: sticky` varia entre `fixed` e `relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning)).

Simplificando, quero tirar as sombras da última coluna quando a barra de rolagem estiver horizontalmente no fim, e tirar as sombras do *header* quando a barra de rolagem estiver verticalmente no início. Imagino que não dê para fazer isso com CSS, pelo menos [não com um seletor imaginário `:stuck` e `:not(:stuck)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25308823/8839059), por isso adicionei a tag JavaScript.

[No AntDesign tem um exemplo](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-fixed-columns-header) do resultado desejado, mas nesse caso a tabela possui sombras apenas nas colunas fixas, não no *header*.

Apesar de eu não querer soluções com *Scroll Event Listener* por motivos de desempenho (vide [Scroll-linked effects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Scroll-linked_effects)), se alguém solucionar desse jeito, pode compartilhar para ter como referência e ajudar outras pessoas :)

O código está disponível também no [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tabela-com-coluna-e-header-fixos-ftznj).

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 20rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

th,
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  height: 5rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.fixed {
  background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
}

.fixed-top {
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fixed-right {
  border-left: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  box-shadow: -5px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-left: 1rem;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fixed-top.fixed-right {
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    -5px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<main>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="fixed fixed-top">Nome</th>
            <th class="fixed fixed-top">Idade</th>
            <th class="fixed fixed-top">Cidade</th>
            <th class="fixed fixed-top">Estado</th>
            <th class="fixed fixed-top">País</th>
            <th class="fixed fixed-top fixed-right">Linguagem Favorita</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>João da Silva Marques</td>
            <td>15 anos</td>
            <td>São Valentin</td>
            <td>SP</td>
            <td>Brasil</td>
            <td class="fixed fixed-right">Kotlin</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Maria Bernardino de Campos</td>
            <td>35 anos</td>
            <td>Honolulu</td>
            <td>Havaí</td>
            <td>Estados Unidos</td>
            <td class="fixed fixed-right">Swift</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Beatriz Camargo de Albuquerque</td>
            <td>42 anos</td>
            <td>Rio do Sul</td>
            <td>SC</td>
            <td>Brasil</td>
            <td class="fixed fixed-right">JavaScript</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Marquinho Gomes da Silva</td>
            <td>17 anos</td>
            <td>Manaus</td>
            <td>AM</td>
            <td>Brasil</td>
            <td class="fixed fixed-right">Python</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </main>
```

Comment: Eu até estava elaborando uma resposta com base [neste texto](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/sticky-headers), porém o fato de você aplicar `position: sticky` nas células e não na linha atrapalhou um pouco. Como estou sem tempo, acabei desistindo de tentar resolver isso. :D Mas talvez o artigo linkado te dê uma direção. :-)

Comment: Valeu, derei uma lida. Eu acho que, em relação ao header, apliquei nas células e não na linha porque tava dando algum problema quando tentei. Porém, até onde enxergo, pra fixar a última coluna teria que ser nas células mesmo...

Comment: O problema de aplicar na célula é que você terá que aplicar o observador N vezes, sendo N o número de células, o que pode trazer problemas de performance (ou não, quem sabe). Uma outra opção é tentar usar o `parentElement`, aplicando o observador somente na primeira célula – ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Eu até dei uma brincada aqui só com CSS e quase foi... https://imgur.com/a/QNIMCuq mas vou deixar pra vc tentar... Com JS vc pode tentar com o Intersection Observer que as vezes da  certo https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API